# How to convert string to two digits in C#?

Tags: c#

This is a relatively simple matter, I'm trying to convert some string to two digits.

It looks like this:

```
string s="20-30";
```

And I have two int variables:

```
int numA, numB;
```

I want to split it into two int values. So it should be:

```
numA=20; numB=30;
```

It should be pretty simple but I got a little tangled up and I only find examples in C ++. I need to know how to do this in C #?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: `s.Split('-').Select(i=>int.Parse(i)).ToArray();` or even `s.Split('-').Select(int.Parse)`. Split the string first then parse the elements

Comment: If the sizes are fixed, you could parse substrings directly: `var numA=int.Parse(s[0..2]); var numB=int.Parse(s[3,5]);`

Answer (score 2):

```
int numA, numB;

var splt = s.Split('-');

if (splt.Length == 2) {
     int.TryParse(splt[0], out numA);
     int.TryParse(splt[1], out numB);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string is in the specified format:

```
int[] split = s.Split('-').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
numA = split[0];
numB = split[1];
```

Comment: The result is an `int[]`, not a `string[]`